# Est-il correct d'utiliser l'expression « à la hauteur de » ?

Tags: expressions, locutions

Dans le cadre d'une campagne de financement, il nous faut envoyer des lettres à différentes compagnies afin d'obtenir des subventions.

Est-il correct d'utiliser l'expression « à la hauteur de » dans la phrase suivante :

> Nous demandons, s'il serait possible pour la (compagnie|organisation), de nous financer à la hauteur de [montant].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

L'expression est utilisable, mais sans l'article « la »:

> financer à  <strike>la</strike>  hauteur de...

Comment: @Laure: Précise au centime?

Comment: À hauteur de peut introduire une somme très précise. Multiples exemples vérifiales dans google, y compris des documents fiscaux émanant du ministère du budget !

Comment: Au temps pour moi alors, je retire :)

Comment: bien sûr, si on a besoin des centimes.

Comment: J'aurais tendance à utiliser _à [concurrence](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/concurrence) de_.

Comment: Laure : d'accord, bonnes sources, sauf Google quand il est cité en général car il peut tout aussi bien faire ressortir une erreur populaire.